# Get-NetTCPConnection trazer o count de eventos

Tags: powershell

Como consigo contar a quantidade de retorno usando esse parametro do powershell?

No cmd eu consigo executar o comando abaixo:

```html
C:\Users\admin>netstat -ano |find "8000"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       14112

C:\Users\admin>
C:\Users\admin>netstat -ano |find "8000" /c
1
```

Existe algum similar para o PowerShell ? Eu preciso que o resultado seja gravado junto com uma data e hora.

Ex: 1 - 18/12/2019 22:00:00

Answer (score 3):

Segue abaixo:

```
"" + (Get-NetTCPConnection | where { $_.RemotePort -eq 443}).Count + " - " + (Get-Date)
```